# Delay in Promise.all won't work if increase sleep time after call sleep function

Tags: javascript, typescript

delay I found interesting behavior while coding in JS.

As seen in the following code, starting with `sleep(0)` doesn't make any delay, while `sleep(15)` does.

```js
// sleep.ts
export default function sleep(t: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
```

```js
// loop.ts
async function doLoop() {
  let delay = 0;
  const increment = 15;

  await Promise.all(
    new Array(10).fill(0).map(async () => {
        // This doesn't work. There's no delay.
        await sleep(delay);
        delay += increment;

        // This works.
        delay += increment;
        await sleep(delay);
      }
    )
  )
}
```

What's the difference between the two?

Try it below.

```js
// sleep.ts
function sleep(t){
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
// loop.ts
async function doLoop() {
  let delay = 0;
  const increment = 1000;

  await Promise.all(
    new Array(3).fill(0).map(async () => {
        // This doesn't work. There's no delay.
        await sleep(delay);
        console.log(1, delay);
        delay += increment;

        // This works.
        delay += increment;
        await sleep(delay);
        console.log(2, delay);
      }
    )
  )
}

doLoop();
```

Comment: How do you know there's no delay on the first sleep?

Comment: I used `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to found out.

Comment: But your initial delay is just 0 millisecond when it runs doesn't that explain why there's no delay?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your comment properly. I thought you are talking about the whole loop. Might there's no delay on the first loop however I meant the whole loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

The `map()` callback function creates a new execution scope/context for each item in the Array, using the current values of `delay` and `increment`, before pushing it into the callback queue, where it awaits execution.

During execution, the first `await sleep(delay)` for each callback is executed with a `delay` of `0ms`;

**Let's think Event loop & Closures in JavaScript**

**Call Stack**

> The call stack is part of the event loop process, it basically holds
> the state of the currently running function. It's pretty similar to
> the concept of stack data structure. (LIFO - Last In First Out)

Now, when the `doLoop()` function is called it's added to the call stack, and during execution, it initializes variables `delay` and `increment` and assigns the values `0` and `1000` respectively.

Next, it runs the `await Promise.all()` which is also added to the call stack to start execution.

Next, `new Array(3).fill(0)` is added to the call stack, executed, and afterward returns `[0, 0, 0]`, and this return value is chained to `Array.map()`, which is added to the call stack as well to start execution.

> `Array.map()` is a higher-order function that starts a loop, performs
> an operation on each item in the loop and returns a new array

**Callback Queue**

> This is another part of the event loop process, where your asynchronous code gets pushed to, and waits for the
> execution. Functions are lined up here in a queue, and the call stack looks here to grab stuff to execute next when it's done.

The chained `.map()` function takes a callback function which is pushed into the callback queue accordingly because they're asynchronous functions.

**Closures**

> This is when a function remembers the scope/context where it has been created
> even when the function is executed in a different scope.

When each callback is pushed into the callback queue a new execution scope/context is created based on the current values of `delay` and `increment`.

The first `await sleep(delay)` is executed with a `delay` value of `0` because that's the value of `delay` when it was pushed into the call stack.

While the second `await sleep(delay)` is executed in the call stack after delay has been incremented, thereby causing an actual wait.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! So based on my understanding, in the first case, all the `sleep` functions are pushed back in callback queue then all the increment happen after each  `sleep` function is done. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: *all the increment -> each increment